# Minimum value for pingInterval and pingTimeout in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, engine.io

I am working on a real time game app. The problem I am facing is that I am getting a `disconnect` event from the Android client even though the connection is still valid from there. By researching I found that this issue might be resolved by having a suitable combination of pingInterval and pingTimeout values for the io. Can someone please suggest a solution for this? And also the minimum value of pingInterval and pingTimeout which can be set for solving the issue?

Current configuration which I am using:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  pingInterval: 2000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
});
```

Comment: Under what client conditions, does the server receive a disconnect?  Does the client go idle?  Does the client app leave the foreground?  This could just be an Android battery management issue as it tries to keep your app from grinding down the battery with continual transmissions when it isn't in the foreground or isn't being used.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not able to reproduce the disconnect event, it is happening randomly(Now with less frequency). The client doesn't go idle. The client app doesn't leave the foreground. It might be caused due to the Android battery management issue.

Comment: Also I couldn't find the minimum acceptable value for the pingInterval and pingTimeout values. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.